# Replacing file content in PHP

Tags: php, file, file-io, preg-replace, replace

I need a function just like [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) but instead of strings I need it to work with files / file content.

Comment: You could pull file contents into a variable by looping over it using fread and then work with preg_replace as you would with a string of text ?

Comment: Yes but then the updated content should be written into the files it was taken from.

Comment: So what is the problem to write the content back to the file?

Comment: You could use the Unix utility `sed`.

Comment: PHP supports binary data in strings.
Note there is a comment in the manual that the preg fns don't like strings greater than ~100k. However it probably will have problems with null chars in the source string - so read the file in chunks of up to (say) 10k, delimited by nulls, strip any trailing null (and keep it for later), apply the preg to each chunk and write it out again adding the null back if you removed one.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You can do:

```
$file = 'filename';
file_put_contents($file,str_replace('find','replace',file_get_contents($file)));
```

Answer (score 26):

@codaddict's answer is quite sufficent for small files (and would be how I would implement it if the size of the file was under a MiB).  However it will eat up a ton of memory, and as such you should be careful when reading large files.

If you want a much more memory friendly version, you could use [stream filters](https://www.php.net/manual/en/stream.filters.php)...

```
class ReplaceText_filter extends php_user_filter {
    protected $search = '';
    protected $replace = '';
    
    public function filter($in, $out, &$consumed, $closing) {
        while ($bucket = stream_bucket_make_writable($in)) {
            $bucket->data = str_replace(
                $this->search, 
                $this->replace, 
                $bucket->data
            );
            $consumed += $bucket->datalen;
            stream_bucket_append($out, $bucket);
        }
        return PSFS_PASS_ON;
    }

    public function onCreate() {
        if (strpos($this->filtername, '.') === false) return false;
        list ($name, $arguments) = explode('.', $this->filtername, 2);
        $replace = '';
        $search = $arguments;
        if (strpos($arguments, '|') !== false) {
            list ($search, $replace) = explode('|', $arguments, 2);
        }
        if (strpos($search, ',') !== false) {
            $search = explode(',', $search);
        }
        if (strpos($replace, ',') !== false) {
            $search = explode(',', $replace);
        }
        $this->search = $search;
        $this->replace = $replace;
    }
}
stream_filter_register('replacetext.*', 'ReplaceText_Filter');
```

So, then you can append an arbitrary stream filter.  The filter's name determines the arguments:

```
$search = 'foo';
$replace = 'bar';
$name = 'replacetext.'.$search.'|'.$replace;
stream_filter_append($stream, $name);
```

or for arrays,

```
$search = array('foo', 'bar');
$replace = array('bar', 'baz');
$name = 'replacetext.'.implode(',', $search).'|'.implode(',', $replace);
stream_filter_append($stream, $name);
```

Obviously this is a really simple example (and doesn't do a lot of error checking), but it allows you to do something like this:

```
$f1 = fopen('mysourcefile', 'r');
$f2 = fopen('mytmpfile', 'w');
$search = array('foo', 'bar');
$replace = array('bar', 'baz');
$name = 'replacetext.'.implode(',', $search).'|'.implode(',', $replace);
stream_filter_append($f1, $name);
stream_copy_to_stream($f1, $f2);
fclose($f1);
fclose($f2);
rename('mytmpfile', 'mysourcefile');
```

And that will keep memory usage very low while processing potentially huge (GiB or TiB) files...

Oh, and the other cool thing, is it can inline edit differing stream types.  What I mean by that is that you can read from a HTTP stream, edit inline, and write to a file stream.  It's quite powerful (as you can chain these filters)...

Comment: The only problem with this answer is when the search terms are located across buckets, especially when dealing with files larger than 8 KiB.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$pattern = "/created/";
$replacement = "XXXXX";
$file_name = "regex.txt";
$getting_file_contents = file_get_contents($file_name);

echo("Original file contents : " . "<br><br>");
var_dump($getting_file_contents);
echo("<br><br><br>");

if ($getting_file_contents == true) {
  echo($file_name . " had been read succesfully" . "<br><br><br>");

  $replace_data_in_file = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $getting_file_contents);
  $writing_replaced_data = file_put_contents($file_name, $replace_data_in_file);
  echo("New file contents : " . "<br><br>");
  var_dump($replace_data_in_file);
  echo("<br><br>");

  if ($writing_replaced_data == true) {
    echo("Data in the file changed");
  }
  else {
    exit("Cannot change data in the file");
  }
}
else {
  exit("Unable to get file contents!");
}

?>
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation to this code? else it would be classified as a low quality answer

Comment: its basic php functions , you can just get the explanation from https://www.php.net/docs.php