# How can I open a linux file in php?

Tags: php, linux, file, ubuntu, replace

I'm trying to make an installer for my PHP project. I need to add the following block into `<VirtualHost *:80>`. Here is a part of my installer script:

```
<?php

$path = "/var/www/html/myProject";

$default_conf = shell_exec('cat /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf');

$new_directory = "<Directory $path/public>
                     Allow Override all
                     Require all granted
                  </Directory>";

$res = str_replace("</VirtualHost>","$new_directory</VirtualHost>", $default_conf);

file_put_contents("/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf",$res);
```

But `$default_conf` is empty. Why? How can I fix it?

---

Noted that the result of this command in the command line environment

```
cat /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

is the content of `000-default.conf` file which is exactly as expected *(it is not empty)*.

Comment: Have you tried with `error_reporting ( E_ALL );
ini_set ( 'display_errors', 1 );` at the top - you'll probably get a 'Permission denied' message.

Comment: @NigelRen The name of my script is `installer.php` and I ran this command already: `sudo chmod 777 installer.php`

Comment: looks like web server user does not have privileges to do or you may need absolute path for your `cat` command

Comment: Isn't `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` absolute ?

Comment: The permissions of your script has nothing to do with it , I've just tried to run almost the same code and it's the message I get, so have you tried with error reporting?

Comment: @NigelRen Yes I've tried those two lines *(added at top of my script)*, but sadly still the result is blank.

Comment: Is your path to the file correct?

Comment: @Progrock Yes, that's correct. By the way, the problem is why `$default_conf` is empty ...

Comment: @stack I only mention it because that symlink is named without the extension under my Debian.  Have you tried reading any old file?  Did file_get_contents work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have a permissions problem with running the shell command.

Why not try the function **file_get_contents** which is simpler, safer and cross platform.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Further, you can use **file_exists** and **is_readable** to double check everything and help with debugging.

Comment: You're right. using `file_get_contents()` seems cleaner https://stackoverflow.com/a/3575012/5259594