# PHP open a php file and replace content

Tags: php, fopen, str-replace

I wanna to open a php file and replace the content I tried this code but it didn't work,

```
$fh = fopen("c/".$file."/underbaba.php", 'w');
$file = file_get_contents($fh);
$file = str_replace('error":4,', 'error":0,', $file);
```

This system open my file and delete all the code in file underbaba.php, I need a code because I have a lot of files to edit I used `scandir` and `foreach` for reading files in all directory `c` with name `underbaba.php`, Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing file content in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574999/replacing-file-content-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

**Your problem:**

If you use `file_get_contents` you don't pass a file handle but the path to the file as a string.

While

```
$fh = fopen("c/".$file."/underbaba.php", 'w');
```

without writing to the file with `fwrite` will result in simply erasing the file. Also the file should be `fclose`d before the script ends.

---

**The solution:**

Simply Use `file_get_contents` to read the file then `file_put_contents` to write.

```
$contents = file_get_contents( $full_path_to_file );
$contents = str_replace( 'error":4,', 'error":0,', $contents );
file_put_contents( $full_path_to_file, $contents );
```

You get a very little overhead versus using a sequence of `fopen`, `fread`, `fseek`, `fwrite`, `fclose` because the file is opened and closed twice but I don't think this is an issue.

Worth mentioning that `file_get_contents` will read all the whole file at once and store it into memory so this solution is feasable only with files with a reasonable size.

---

You may add error handling easily:

```
$contents = file_get_contents( $full_path_to_file );
if( $contents === false )
{
    // an error occurred reading
}

$contents = str_replace( 'error":4,', 'error":0,', $contents );

$bytes_written = file_put_contents( $full_path_to_file, $contents );
if( $bytes_written !== strlen( $contents ) )
{
    // an error occurred writing
}
```

---

As you're operating on a set of files setup a `for` / `foreach` loop setting `$full_path_to_file` properly at each iteration.

---

For your reference:

[**file_get_contents**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

[**file_put_contents**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

Comment: then either the path to the file is wrong or you don't have permissions to read and write the file. Do you get an error or what?

Answer (score 0):

You need to open your file in `append mode` use mode `a+` or `r+` for this

Please check the below link for help
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_open.asp

Answer (score 0):

If that is all you are doing, then yes you are emptying your file. According to the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php):

> 'w'   Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the beginning of
>   the file and **truncate the file to zero length**. If the file does
>   not exist, attempt to create it.

Are you writing the string you have modified back to the file somewhere as well?

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient and understandable workaround to manage file contents with methods as `file_put_contents()` for me is wrapped in the function below.

Worked great for me and seemed to be much faster than the previous function I used, which included `fopen()`, `file_put_contents()` and many more resource consuming functions. This function also works well with large files of code.

```php
function replace_contents( $path, $string, $replace ) {
    $str_to_arr = preg_split( "#/#", $path );
    $file_name  = array_pop( $str_to_arr );
    $dir        = implode( '/',$str_to_arr );
    
    if ( is_file($path) ) {
        return exec(
            'cd ' . $dir . PHP_EOL .
            "sed -i 's/" . $string . "/" . $replace . "/g' " . $file_name
        );
    }
}
```

- `$str_to_arr` - String to array conversion (including the file)
- `$file_name`  - Get the last index of the above array (the actual file name)
- `$dir`        - Get the the actual path (without the file name) so

And finally use `exec()` to perform a simple Unix command which replaces the inner file content located in the path passed to the function params.

`sed 's/unix/linux/g' geekfile.txt`