# PHP finding word from different file

Tags: php

Assume `data.php` has three variables like below:

```
$first = 1;
$second = 1;
$third = 1;
```

My question is how to get the `1` from `$second` and change it to `3`? So it becomes:

```
$first = 1;
$second = 3;
$third = 1;
```

I'm trying to do this from another file, let's say `index.php`. I have refer to the below answer but I don't know what should I put in the `find` of the method below? ( The below code is from `index.php` )

`file_put_contents ( $file, str_replace( 'find', 3, file_get_contents ( $file ) ) );`

( https://stackoverflow.com/a/3575012/20454874 )

`str_replace('$second = 1;', '$second = 3')` only works for the first time. Because the value to search for is different already after the first time.

The reason behind it is that I have an HTML input and I want to save the value into the file `data.php`, that's why the `find` ( the first parameter `search` ) is dynamic.

Comment: I've read your question 3 times and i'm still confused. Please state your end goal as well, as the details you provide do not make much sense. You want to find and replace in a (couple of) document(s) and your search string is not specific enough?

Comment: @Techno I'm sorry, I have edited the question, do it looks better now?

Comment: @yobebix932 Did you tried `str_replace('$second = 1;', '$second = 3')`?

Comment: Why are you searching for the value and not the variable name?

Comment: The args for str_replace are explained in the docs https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: @yobebix932 Sound great! But I wonder if there is any method just to search for the number itself. But I will take this if there is no better solution, thank you so much!

Comment: @Techno Because I want to replace the value and not the variable name...

Comment: @AD7six Thanks for the reference, but may I know what should I put in the first parameter `search` in this case?

Comment: The string you want to find - @Justinas already addressed that :). I think you're overcomplicating how to solve your problem by expecting a solution to only find and replace the value. If you _need_ to do that you'll need to explain why, it's unnecessary from what's currently in the question.

Comment: @AD7six I have edited the question, I wish it makes sense to you...

Comment: It made sense before, the edit adds no new info :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regex to find dynamic content:

```php
$newContent = preg_replace('/\$second = \d+;/', '$second = ' . $newValue . ';', $content);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so what I gathered from comments I think I know the solution to your problem:

You are trying to find values in the document, but I think you should be focussing on the key and use [regex](https://regex101.com/r/M6LyyH/1) to extract the value with [preg replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) like so:

```
$content = '$first = 1;
$second = 3;
$third = 1;';

$pattern = '/(\$first = )(\d+);/m';

$replacement = '$1 your_new_value_here';
$replaced = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);
var_dump($replaced);
```

`$pattern` is a regex looking for, in this case the `$first =` section with any number behind it
`$replacement` contains $1, which is the first section of the regex(being literally `$first =` , and the second part is w/e you want to put in as a number

Then I use preg_replace to do the replacement for me. You can search for any key this way, and replace it's value.

PS: Please look at the links provided, the regex one is customized for this use-case.